# Xcode 6 launch failed: timed out trying to launch app on iPad

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ipad

Same basic problem as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26032085/xcode-6-process-launch-failed-timed-out-trying-to-launch-app) but all the fixes listed have not solved the issue for me.  I've used a development provisioning file/cert but with no difference.  (and it worked regardless on my iPhone 6)

Relevant facts:

1) iPad (ios 7.1) has over 2000 provisioning files, 99% of them autogenerated by Apple.  I suspect this is causing the problem, but I can't figure out how to remove them all.  I reset the data on the device, but once I tried to run the app again from Xcode it restored them all again.

2) The same app and same Xcode set-up work fine on my iPhone 6 (ios 8.1).  None of the provisioning files get installed on the iPhone.

3) The app will run on the iPad, but just not with the debugger.  It also takes very long to launch.

I'm stumped and would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Are you performing any major code operations before your first view appears? For example in viewDidLoad or in viewDidAppear?

Comment: No, not really.  And there's no delay on the iPhone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did figure out a way to get rid of the provisioning files, and that has cleared up the problem, at least for now.

To delete all the provisioning files at once do the following:

1. Disconnect the device and turn on Airplane mode.
2. Change the date on the device to a time past the last expiration date on the provisioning.  Then, going to General->Profiles should show all the provisioning files as expired.
3. Restart the device.
4. Go to General->Profiles.  In my case it still showed 2000+ installed but when I went in it only showed one (testflight webclip).  Exit the profiles and it was reset to four.  Refresh one more time and it said just the webclip.
5. Reset time/airplane mode/reconnect.

At this point on my iPad, the correct number of profiles was downloaded and the app now loads from Xcode without any timeouts.

Comment: Wow genius! Saved me tons of time :D

Answer (score 1):

Also changing "Code Signing Identity" from "iOS Distribution" to "iOS Developer" worked for me.

[image]