# Increase timeout when launching iOS app on device from Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7.3

Recently, I've been having problems launching my app on Xcode 7.3. I can run it fine in an emulator, and about 15% of the time it will run fine when I debug it on a device. However, at other times when I debug on the device I see

- "Performing install actions" (which succeeds, since the new binary is on my device)
- "Running (my app)"
- "Could not launch 'MyApp': process launch failed: timed out trying to launch app"

Is there a way to increase the time that the debugger will take to connect? This doesn't appear to be a provisioning/certificate issue, since it sometimes succeeds - it just appears that Xcode is giving up too quickly.

Note that I don't think this is a duplicate of [Could not launch process launch failed: timed out waiting for app to launch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22683419/xcode-5-could-not-launch-process-launch-failed-timed-out-waiting-for-app-to-la) since the app launches - sometimes.

Comment: Could help to delete derived data when Xcode doesn't behave: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18933476/1305067

Comment: That's a good thought; unfortunately that doesn't seem to resolve the issue. I still time out before launching.

Comment: are you using the right certificate?

Comment: I believe I am - the app launches sometimes (with no certificate or code changes). Just not every time.

Comment: @matt - the user's question was *"Is there a way to increase the time that the debugger will take to connect"*. That's different than the cited duplicate and its answers. (There is one comment about quitting iTunes, but it appears to be more comment worthy since its mostly a link-only answer).