# Packaging and Distribution of ios apps locally

Tags: android, ios, share, app-distribution

I was interested in knowing if its possible to share an **ipa file generated from the project between 2 people locally** without the overhead of itunes store or testflight. As in **android apps** we can easily share the compiled **.apk** file with anyone even across borders. I have gone through the following references  https://stackoverflow.com/a/6413247/550177 but i am sure my question is different. Any sort of help would be appriciated

Comment: Do you mean compile an Xcode project and run it on your device?

Comment: In android, i can just send you the apk even though you are across the globe and you can install the app. I wan wondering if its possible to do the same in ios. as i dont know what is the final yeild after compileing the files

Comment: You can make ad-hoc build with udid of the device, export it and then send. But no way like android sending it across a globe. That's why piracy rate is lower in ios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't. You need to have a developer account to test it on iPhone. You may then package your app and deploy to a number of iPhones using their UDIDs.

A UDID can be found in the iTunes when you connect your phone to a Mac. You need to add this UDID to your device list and check that in your provisioning profile in [Member Center](https://developer.apple.com/membercenter/index.action). The app package(ipa) can be uploaded to dropbox and then you may hit a url from phone to install the app.

The url may link to your app in the dropbox something like this:

itms-services://?action=download-manifest&url=https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/XXXXXXX/YourApp.plist

Comment: Whith testflight app you can share the App (?)

Comment: Yes you can do that too but that again requires a developer account.

Answer (score 0):

Export ad-hoc file (*.ipa) and use [Apple Configurator](https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/apple-configurator/id434433123?mt=12) in Mac OS to install the ipa to iDevice which added uuid in ad-hoc provisioning. OR using [enterprise program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/enterprise/) if you don't want to add any iDevices' uuids

Answer (score 0):

[![enter image description here][1]][1]You have two quick options:

- Either generate ipa file and share that ipa file and install that using iTunes in your MAC

  -Or for best installation experience, upload that ipa file to [diawi.com](http://diawi.com), it takes just few seconds to upload and will give you a URL to install app directly in your iOS device.

Please note, you will need to include UDID's of all the devices in your provisional profile, for which you want to install your app.

Comment: is that ipa file the generated out after compiling the project

Comment: Yes, you will need to go to Products-> Archive .

Answer (score 0):

You could share the compiled application if the devices were either:

1. Both registered/provisioned under an Apple developer account (paid)
2. Jailbroken

An (uncompiled) alternative would be (new in Xcode 7+):

1. Share the Xcode project, then compile the project and install on your devices. (free)

Comment: so basically ios does not provide that feature

Comment: What's your goal exactly, are you wanting to share your app with someone you know, or are you thinking of a wider audience? iOS does provide the ability to do what you're wanting (within the current limitations), although whether it's practical or not really depends on the goal.