# How does Push Notifications work while in development and production mode, (pushwoosh)

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, pushwoosh

So i have a question to which i could not find an answer on PushWoosh API or on google.

I have integrated successfully my application to PushWoosh. For people who knows about PushWoosh you can setup the "environment" to use sandbox or production when sending the push notification.

So when i use Sandbox i can send push notifications to my device. When i choose production nothing comes up( im guessing its because i have not launched the application to the AppStore yet?)

So am i to presume that if it works on SandBox mode, i can now upload it to the appstore and switch to production mode and the push notifications should work when the app is downloadable from the appstore?

When creating the SSL Certificates i used the "Apple Push Notification service SSL (Sandbox & Production)".

Thank you for your answers..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test your production mode notifications before releasing it to appstore. Apple provides a mechanism for it. You need to build an AdHoc version of your App. If you are not familiar with Adhoc distribution please refer the below link

[iPhone: Push Notification Testing on Production Certificate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413188/iphone-push-notification-testing-on-production-certificate)

There is no assurance that push notifications will work in production mode if they are working in sandbox mode, so you cannot presume any assumptions. Adhoc distribution is provided by apple to test production mode notifications. Please go through the below link which provides some helpful information.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thank you so much was exactly what i was looking for. I did it step by step and tried to send a push to two devices in production mode and the push notification was received. NOW with this working. I do not need to think about anything more right? like it is ready to be pushed to Appstore right?

Comment: Great.Yes, you can push it to Appstore.@TimoCengiz